# Вопросы с ассоциацией остаются без дополнительных ответов

Tags: обсуждение, перевод-содержимого

Несколько раз я переводил вопрос и ответ с enSO в ruSO. Для меня остаётся непонятным вопрос: почему пользователи не отвечают на вопросы с ассоциацией? То есть перевёл я вопрос, а на него тут больше никто не отвечает. Почему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переводные вопросы+ответы это, считай, то же самое, что само-вопрос-ответ. А на них, как известно, редко приходят  дополнительные новые ответы. Это объясняется тем, что ТС уже уделил существенное время на поиск решения проблемы и чтобы кто-то смог дать еще один ответ, он должен разобраться в проблеме не меньше ТС. Это, безусловно, уменьшает вероятность появления другого ответа.

Answer (score 4):

Может быть просто по той же причине, по которой есть любые неотвеченные вопросы? Самое банальное: никто из причитавших не знал ответ. Или кто-то знал, но вопрос показался не интересным. И много других причин.

Answer (score 1):

Смысла нет.

Обычно вопрос задает человек, которому нужна помощь (даже если это простое любопытство), вот ему и отвечают.

Answer (score -1):

А зачем отвечать на то, на что уже ответили?

Comment: Может есть вариант лучше..

Comment: Но ведь обычно переводится не худший вариант ;)

Comment: но может кто-то и лучше знает...

Comment: Маловероятно же...